# How can I customize toolbar with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, toolbar

Is there any way that I could add a button to NP++'s toolbar?

I have a shortcut which I use quite a lot. That would be nice if I could make a button out of it instead of pressing  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> each time.

Answer (score 20):

There is a plugin "[Customize Toolbar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-customize/)" on [Plugin Resources](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources/#plugins), or simply use Notepad++'s Plugin Manager. Its description says the plugin makes it possible that "buttons for Notepad++ or plugin menu commands can be defined using a configuration file." So it depends if your shortcut is a menu or plugin command. You could give this plugin a try.

You could also redefine the shortcut to something simpler, you only need to find and change the shortcut in the "Settings", "Shortcut mapper" dialog.

Comment: This plugin works great. One thing to note is that the CustomizeToolbar.btn confirmation file might be located in your User / AppData / Roaming directory rather than under the Notepad++ install directory per the pop-up instructions that the plugin gives.

Comment: This plugin is awesome. Be sure to download the correct version for your installation, say x64. If you download the wrong version, or UAC prevents writing to `%ProgramFiles%`, nothing will happen when using`Settings > Import > Import plugin(s)...` (no warning or popup). Recommend manual installation (ie. download > unzip > copy to [INSTALL-PATH]\plugins > restart NPP).

Answer (score 1):

You may also customize the right-click menu inside the editor area using the

> Settings menu >> Edit Popup ContextMenu.

## The issue:

I didn't like how much slower the newer file-tab right-click menu was with:

> Open into >> Open Containing Folder in Explorer

(especially now that it's much more hidden by a recent update).

[image: newer tab right-click menu]

## What to do about it:

So, I simply added this code:

```
<Item MenuEntryName="File" MenuItemName="Explorer"/>
```

such that it's the first item in the popup:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <ScintillaContextMenu>
        <Item MenuEntryName="File" MenuItemName="Explorer"/>
        <Item id="0"/>
```

Now, it is readily available at a moment's notice: Just right-click anywhere in the editing area:

[image]